# How to access different static files for different Django applications on IIS?

Tags: django, fastcgi, django-staticfiles, iis-10

Suppose I have two Django apps: DjangoApp1 and DjangoApp2
I have created a website with DjangoApp1 in IIS with some IP(192.168.1.1) on port 80, and I can access this website on `192.168.1.1/`, the static files are loaded by the virtual directory `static`, and this site is seen perfectly as expected.
Now, for the second app, DjangoApp2, I need to access it through the same IP address in this way: `192.168.1.1/app2/`, so I created an Application in my website with the name **app2** and configured it accordingly. Now, since DjangoApp2 has a different set of static files, I need to configure my server so that it loads those files as well. Since I already have a virtual directory named *static*, I can't create one with the same name. I tried creating app2_static and all other combinations, but these files were not loading. All the other functionalities of this app work correctly, which are not dependent on the local static files.
How do I configure the StaticFileModule so that it loads the necessary files for DjangoApp2, without disturbing the files of DjangoApp1?

I have used FastCgi and wfastcgi module of Django for the deployment configurations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution myself when I was messing around with the `settings.py` file of my "DjangoApp2". I first considered to add the static files of my *DjangoApp2* to the static directory of *DjangoApp1*, but I thought it could be very inefficient, so I started tweaking some changes in my *settings.py* file.
So, instead of changing something in the IIS server, I simply changed my `STATIC_URL`.
So, first I created a virtual directory for my static files and named it `app2_static`. Its physical path was `BASE_DIR/static`.

> The BASE_DIR is the directory where the **manage.py** file of `DjangoApp2` is located.

Then, I changed the `STATIC_URL` to `'/app2_static/'`. Then I restarted the IIS server and the static files were loading on the webpage.

> Make sure that your `web.config` file in the static directory of your DjangoApp2 contains only StaticFileModule and no FastCGIModule.

Answer (score 0):

make sure this is in `settings.py`

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Store your static files in a folder called static inside your app folders, so:

```
DjangoApp1/static/DjangoApp1/example.jpg.
DjangoApp2/static/DjangoApp2/example.jpg.
```

i got the above from the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/)

also for deployment u need to run `collectstatic` and let django generate all ur static files into 1 folder for you. here is [the link about this in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/deployment/)

Comment: This works for just 1 application. If I try to add another application under the same website (as mentioned in the question), it still fetches the static files from the *static* virtual directory.

Comment: oh ok, sorry about that. I would use nginx to handle something like this then

Comment: I have never worked with nginx, so I don't know how to work with that. Instead, I found a simple way to access the static files of the second app. You can check my answer for that.